# How to get the C pointer array length?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [length of array in function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

Is there any method like the Java can .length from a C point array? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

No, given a C pointer you cannot determine it's length in a platform agnostic manner.

For an actual C array though see dirkgently's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637079/how-to-get-the-c-pointer-array-length/3637165#3637165)

Comment: The question is not very clear; You can always get the array length if its definition is local in scope ;-)

Comment: @dirkgently, I agree, it's unclear if they're asking for a pointer length or array length.  I redirected them to your answer for the latter

Answer (score 3):

You could get it using a macro:

```
#define sizeofa(array) sizeof array / sizeof array[ 0 ]
```

if and only if the array is automatic and you access it in the scope of its definition as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
   printf("%zd\n", sizeofa( x ));
   return 0;
}
```

However, if you only have a (decayed) pointer you cannot get the array length without resorting to some non-portable implementation specific hack.

Comment: *z* _Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed integer type corresponding to size_t argument._

Comment: That macro needs a lot more parentheses to avoid common macro problems.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry: Yes, I thought I should add that but then feeling lazy ...

Comment: @dirk there is no %z in my K&R2

Comment: That's from C99. K&R2 is old and a lot of water has since flown under the bridge as they say. Search for a document called n1124.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MSVC/MinGW there is a NONPORTABLE solution for a real C-pointer:

```
#include <malloc.h>
char *s=malloc(1234);
#ifdef __int64
printf( "%lu\n", _msize(s));
#else
#endif
```

For a real C-Array like

```
AnyType myarray[] = {...};
```

or

```
AnyType myarray[constVal];
```

see the other answer.

Comment: you can't assume, that you have a pointer from malloc.

Comment: @fazo, you certainly can assume it's from malloc.  It's just a terrible idea :)