# not able to get the length of an integer array

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [length of array in function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

I am trying to get the length of an integer array but i am not getting the right answer

```
void main()
{
    int x[]={33,55,77};
    printf("%d",getLength(x));//outputs 1
    printf("%d",sizeof(x)/sizeof(int));//outputs 3
}

int getLength(int *inp)
{
    return sizeof(inp)/sizeof(int);
}
```

So why is getLength returning value 1 instead of 3 ?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html

Comment: This question or one like it has been asked hundreds of times at SO. I wonder where people think the size of a C array is stored in memory.

Comment: @JimBalter Because in many other languages it is :):):)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please read my comment again ... I wrote "where", not "why". If people do not understand the C storage model, they have no business writing C code; they certainly will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays *decay* to pointers, you cannot perform length calculation in a function: the function gets a pointer, not an array. You need to do the computations inline the way your function does when it prints `3`, or use a macro to compute array length:

```
#define GET_LENGTH(inp) (sizeof(inp)/sizeof(*inp))
```

[Here is a link to a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/nTX4vN)

Answer (score 3):

Because arrays aren't pointers, and pointers aren't arrays. `sizeof(pointer)` is not the same as `sizeof(the array which the pointer points to)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof(inp)` here is returning the size of pointer and not the size of array and the size of pointer = 4

So

```
sizeof(inp)/sizeof(int)
 ^__ 4        ^__ 4      = 1
```