# Memory in valgrind

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I'm having an issue with memory inn valgrind.  I've been trying to figure out what's wrong but I can't seem to find it.  Here is my issue:

```
==32233== Invalid write of size 1
==32233==    at 0x4C2E1E0: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32233==    by 0x4010C7: songCopy (song.c:102)
==32233==    by 0x4009E6: main (songtest.c:82)
==32233==  Address 0x51fda09 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==32233==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32233==    by 0x4010A4: songCopy (song.c:101)
==32233==    by 0x4009E6: main (songtest.c:82)
```

And this is where the issue is.

```
song *songCopy(const song *s)
{
//song *d = NULL ;
mtime *tmp = NULL ;

song *d = malloc(sizeof(song));

d->artist = malloc(sizeof(s->artist) + 1) ;
strcpy(d->artist, s->artist) ;

d->title = malloc(sizeof(s->title) + 1) ;
strcpy(d->title, s->title) ;

if (NULL != s->lastPlayed)
{
    // copy the last played
    tmp = mtimeCopy(s->lastPlayed) ;
    d->lastPlayed = tmp ;
}
else
{
    // set lastPlayed to NULL
    d->lastPlayed = NULL ;
}
return d ;
```

}

I've tried dereferencing and adding more space to malloc.  I know it's going wrong in the strcpy but I'm not sure why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [length of array in function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the declaration of `song`, but from the usage it looks like its `artist` and `title` members are `char*` pointers. You can use `sizeof` to measure an array, but not a block pointed to by the pointer. `sizeof` is the same for all `char*` pointers on your machine, no matter how long is the string to which they point.

You need to use `strlen(str)+1` instead of `sizeof(str)+1` to fix this problem:

```
d->artist = malloc(strlen(s->artist) + 1) ;
strcpy(d->artist, s->artist) ;

d->title = malloc(strlen(s->title) + 1) ;
strcpy(d->title, s->title) ;
```