# Converting a string to Upper case letters and zeros in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to create a function that accepts a string and converts all lowercase letters to uppercase and everything else into zeros then prints the string. Here is what I have:

```
void upperAndZeros(char* toUpper) {
    char *toReturn[(sizeof(toUpper) / sizeof(*toUpper)) + 1];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; toUpper[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (toUpper[i] >= 'a' && toUpper[i] <= 'z') {
            toReturn[i] = (char) toupper(toUpper[i]); //this is line 127 in the code
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = (char) 0;
        }
    }
    toReturn[i] = '\0';
    printf("The modified string is '%s'", toReturn);
}
```

But when I go to compile this I get the following error:

```
127:25 warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to `char` in a `char *` array here

```
toReturn[i] = (char) toupper(toUpper[i]);
```

You want an array of `char` not `char *`. Change this line

```
char *toReturn[(sizeof(toUpper) / sizeof(*toUpper)) + 1];
```

to

```
char toReturn[(sizeof(toUpper) / sizeof(*toUpper)) + 1];
```

---

Another change that you should do, which was suggested in the comment is, `sizeof()` won't work here, as an array decays into a pointer when passed onto a function. `sizeof(toUpper)` would return the size of a pointer. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument) to understand the problem.

Use `strlen()` here, if the string pointed by `toUpper` is NUL terminated.

If not then send the length separately to the function as another parameter.

Comment: `sizeof()` is a non-sense here! You need `strlen`!

Comment: In fact, you need `strlen(toUpper) + 1`, as @Jean-BaptisteYunès points out.  Also, the `0` needs to be `'0'`; otherwise, the output will stop at the first character that isn't lower-case alpha in the input (something [ProWi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2328163/prowi) pointed out in a now deleted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems, something like this should work better:

```
void upperAndZeros(char* toUpper) {
    char toReturn[strlen(toUpper) + 1];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; toUpper[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (islower(toUpper[i])) {
            toReturn[i] = (char) toupper(toUpper[i]);
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = '0'; // beware not 0 but char '0'
        }
    }
    toReturn[i] = '\0';
    printf("The modified string is '%s'", toReturn);
}
```