# "Incomplete Type Is Not Allowed" Error

Tags: c++, class, c++11, opengl

"sizeof(points)" is the part that is throwing the error (Marked below). I don't know what is going on / what is wrong. I am new to OpenGL and I am experimenting with what I have learned to make it possible to have multiple triangles drawn hence the class. I have also placed the code in a [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/DwVx3zcp)

## VertexObject.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

class VertexObject
{

public:
    VertexObject ( );

    void SetArray ( GLfloat Points [] );

    void SetBuffer ( GLuint* VBO );

    GLfloat Points [ ] = {
         1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f,
         0.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f,
        -1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f
    };

private:



};
```

## VertexObject.cpp

```
#include "VertexObject.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

void VertexObject::SetArray ( GLfloat Points [ ] )
{

    //Generate Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vaoID1;
    //Generates an array for the VAO
    glGenVertexArrays ( 1 , &vaoID1 );
    //Assigns the array to the Vertex Array Object
    glBindVertexArray ( vaoID1 );

    //Fills in the array

    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof ( Points ); i++ ) //Error occurs here
    {

        this->Points [ i ] = Points [ i ];

    }

}

void VertexObject::SetBuffer ( GLuint* VBO )
{

    //Generate Vertex Buffer Object
    glGenBuffers ( 1 , VBO );
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , *VBO );
    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER ,sizeof(Points) , Points , GL_STATIC_DRAW );

}
```

Comment: It means you have not defined Points anywhere.

Comment: It is defined in the header file

Comment: And even when I use "this->points", it still throws the error

Comment: Yes but probably you have just declared it, not defined.
Declaration: struct Points;
Definition: struct Points { ... };

Comment: It's not a struct. Read the header code

Comment: @JamesYeoman Doesn't error occur in `VertexObject::SetBuffer`? `Points` is not in scope, but you're still using it.

Comment: @JamesYeoman Anyway, do you know that what're you trying to do won't work? `sizeof(Points)` won't give you number of elements in array, but sizeof pointer pointing to that array since array decays to pointers when passed to function.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument

Answer (score 1):

As PcAF said, `sizeof(Points)` give you the size of pointer, not the number of element in array `Points`.

You can think that you can substitute `sizeof(Points)` with `sizeof(this->Points)` but there is another problem: `sizeof(this->Points)` don't give you 9 (the number of elements) but `9 * sizeof(GLfloat)`.

So you should use `sizeof(Points)/sizeof(Points[0])`

But I think the bigger problem is that

```
GLfloat Points [ ] = {
     1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f,
     0.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f,
    -1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f
};
```

isn't valid C++11 (C++11 and not C++98 because in class initialization of non-static data member is a C++11 feature) because for in class array you must explicit the size, so

```
GLfloat Points [ 9 ] = {
     1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f,
     0.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f,
    -1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f
};
```

But if you must explicit the size, you could memorize it in a static member, something like

```
static const std::size_t  pointsSize = 9;
GLfloat Points [ pointsSize ] = {
     1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f,
     0.0f , 1.0f , 1.0f,
    -1.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f
};
```

and use it in the cycle, in this way

```
for ( auto i = 0U ; i < pointsSize ;  ++i ) 
 { this->Points [ i ] = Points [ i ]; }
```

Comment: What I don't get is that it works in SetArray but not in SetBuffer.

Comment: @JamesYeoman - 
Sorry but I'm not sure to understand your last comment (it's my fault: I'm not English native speaker): are you saying that my suggestion works correctly in `setArray()` but doesn't work in `setBuffer()`? Anyway, take in count that the use of `sizeof(Points)` in `setBuffer()` it's a completely different thing. (continue)

Comment: @JamesYeoman - (continue) First: in `setBuffer()` `Points` isn't covered by a method parameter, so `sizeof(Points)` it's like `sizeof(this->Points)`. Second: in `setBuffer()` you need the size of the array, not the number of the elements, so if you use `pointSize` calling `getBufferData()`, you use only a part (a fourth?) of `Points`. Conclusion (if I'm not wrong): `sizeof(Points)` in `setBuffer()` should remain `sizeof(Points)`