# Calculate length of double pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a double pointer Array of a structure:

```
typedef struct Position{
    int x;
    int y;
} Position;

Position** array = (Position**)malloc(sizeof(Position*)*10); //10 elements
array[0] = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position*));
array[0]->x = 10;
array[0]->y = 5;
```

Can I calculate the length of set array and if so, how?

The normal way for arrays does not work :

```
int length = sizeof(<array>)/sizeof(<array>[0]);
```

Comment: You can't use `std::array`?

Comment: Not in this case. It is for educational purposes!

Comment: it's an array of pointer, so probably you want to do `malloc(sizeof(Position*)*10)`

Comment: Where is your array? There are only pointers!

Comment: @yar Corrected!

Comment: Define "does not work." Compile error? Result wrong? Something else entirely?

Comment: @Olaf you can define an array in multiple ways! In C/C++ you can allocate space and use pointers!

Comment: @anonymoose The calculated length is always 0!

Comment: @PrinzJuliano: No, you cannot! A pointer is not an array! One of the effects is exactly what you see here! Instead of insisting on wrong assumptions, please think about it. The details will be explained in a good C book. It might be different in the language C/C++, but then don't use the C or C++ tags, as these three are pairwise different languages (one of them does not even exist - find out which).

Comment: @PrinzJuliano: Maybe on your platform, but not guaranteed.

Comment: and `array[0] = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position*))` should be `array[0] = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position))`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of array in function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @Olaf I am using C++ there! It would error in gcc if I did not cast it!

Comment: See, that's **one** reason why you should not double-tag! (as a sidenote: don't use the language names in the title; that's exactly what the tag is for)

Comment: Pick a language.  C is not C++, and C++ is not C.  C/C++ is not a thing.

Comment: All this talk of `C/C++` reminds me of when `Java/JavaScript` was a thing :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Old question, but in case someone needs it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
int main()
{
    char **double_pointer_char;
    ...
    int length_counter = 0;
    while(double_pointer_char[length_counter])
        length_counter++;
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have dynamically allocated an array, there is no way of finding out the number of elements in it.

I once heard of some hacky way to obtain the size of a memory block, (msize) which would allegedly allow you to infer the size of the data within the block, but I would advice against any such weird tricks, because they are not covered by the standard, they represent compiler-vendor-specific extensions.

So, the only way to know the size of your array is to keep the size of the array around.  Declare a `struct`, put the array and its length in the struct, and use that instead of the naked array.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++!

Comment: @Mike Nakis Thanks

Comment: @PrinzJuliano: There is no such language!

Comment: @PrinzJuliano If you are using C/C++ perhaps you should tag your question with the C/C++ language tag.

Answer (score 0):

As you marked the question as C++, I would suggest that you use `std::vector`, then, after you "allocated some memory" (or requested some memory to allocated by `std::vector` constructor or by using `push_back`, or `resize`), you can simply get the size back using by using `std::vector::size`.

```
typedef struct Position{
    int x;
    int y;
} Position;

std::vector<Position> array(10);
array[0].x = 10;
array[0].y = 5;
size_t size = array.size(); // will be 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Having only a pointer to some memory block, you cannot defer the size of this memory block. So you cannot defer the number of elements in it.

For arrays of pointers, however, you could infer the number of elements in it under the following conditions:

1. make sure that every pointer (except the last one) points to a valid object.
2. for the last pointer in the array, make sure that it is always `NULL`.

Then you can derive the length by counting until you reach `NULL`.

Maybe there are some other similar strategies.

Solely from the pointer itself, however, you cannot derive the number of elements in it.