# Invalid types 'float[int]' for array subscript while trying to get the column length of an 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

While trying to multiply 2 matrices

```
void Multiply(float* A, float* B, float* C)
{
    int m = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int p = sizeof(A[0]) / sizeof(A[0][0]);
    int n = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0;i < m;i++)
        for (j = 0;j < n;j++)
        {
            C[n*i + j] = 0;
            for (k = 0;k < p;k++)
                C[n*i + j] = C[n*i + j] + A[p*i + k] * B[n*k + j];
        }
}
```

I get the error `invalid types 'float[int]' for array subscript` at this line

```
int p = sizeof(A[0]) / sizeof(A[0][0]);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `A[0][0]`? What did you try to achieve by that? In any case, the `sizeof` trick is pointless in this context. This trick only works with arrays.

Comment: `sizeof(A)` is a size of a pointer, not an array.

Comment: This is partly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument), but, given the misconception about two-dimensional arrays, it is a superset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the routine that calls `Multiply`, `A` might be defined as `float A[X][Y];`. However, `Multiply` receives only a pointer, not an array. Also, `Multiply` receives no information about the sizes of the original arrays, so they cannot be calculated in the subroutine. They must be passed by the caller.

When an array is used in an expression, including a function argument but excluding the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` (or a string literal used to initialize an array), it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

If `A` is an array of `X` arrays of `Y` `float`, then the first element of `A` is an array of `Y` `float`. Therefore, when `A` is used as a function argument, it is automatically converted to the type `float (*)[Y]`. This is different from the parameter declaration, which is `float *`. A pointer to an array of `float` is not compatible with a pointer to a `float`, and your compiler should warn you about that.

If you nonetheless compile the program with warnings ignored, or a cast to override the types, then `Multiply` has only a `float *` for `A`. It has no information about the size of the array or the fact that is an array of arrays. Then, in the expression `sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0])` (in which the parentheses are unnecessary), `sizeof(A)` is the size of a pointer to `float`, because `A` is a pointer to `float`, and sizeof(A[0])`is the size of a`float`, because`A[0]`is a`float`(as it must be since`A`in`Multiply`is a`float *`).

The parameter `B` has the same problem with the size calculation. In `Multiply`, `B` is only a pointer to `float`, size `sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0])` calculates only the size of a pointer divided by the size of a `float`. It does not provide the size of the original array.

Oddly, your code uses `A` both as a two-dimensional array, in `A[0][0]`, and a one-dimensional array, in `A[p*i + k]`. You must choose one of these.

If your compiler supports variable length arrays, then you can declare `Multiply` as:

```
void Multiply(int m, int p, int n, float (*A)[p], float (*B)[n], float (*C)[n])
```

Then you can use `A[i][k]`, `B[k][j]`, and `C[i][j]` in the routine. In the calling routine, you would write the original arrays as arguments, as with `Multiply(X, Y, Z, A, B, C)`, where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the necessary dimensions.

An alternative is to pass the arrays as pointers to `float` instead of pointers to variable length arrays:

```
void Multiply(int m, int p, int n, float *A, float *B, float *C)
```

Then you would use `A[p*i + k]` and such as your current code shows. In the calling routine, you would pass pointers to the `[0][0]` elements of the arrays:  `Multiply(X, Y, Z, &A[0][0], &B[0][0], &C[0][0])`.

Pedantically, this may have aliasing and pointer arithmetic problems since the resulting code accesses `float` elements using index calculations outside the nominal arrays. It is commonly supported in compilers, but you ought to check.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Lesson learned. Thank you Sir.