# Printing Function in C - Should there be a pointer value or what?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

 
void Array_Print_Fun(int array[]) 
{
    int i;
    int size_of_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    for ( i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
        printf("The %d term is %d \n",i,array[i]);
    }
}


int main()  // MAIN 
{
    int Number_array[] = {1,3,2,5,6}; 
    Array_Print_Fun(Number_array);
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to the C syntax , pointer concept and I am still learning it.
I tried to make a printing function for arrays and I learned that to get the length of an array I have to make this operation:

`int size_of_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);`

and I want to have it in that function so it would take less operations in main and the function as itself would have less parameters.

But still, it gives me an an error.

Should I make somehow a pointer to it ?

Comment: Or maybe a better duplicate: [Length of array in function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8269048/364696)

Comment: @RicardoXD, `size_t size_of_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);` is good when `array` is an _array_.  Yet with `void Array_Print_Fun(int array[])`, `array` is **not** an _array_, but a pointer.  Instead, pass into `Array_Print_Fun()` the array element count: `Array_Print_Fun(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]), Number_array);` and adjust to `void Array_Print_Fun(size_t n, int array[])`