# Segfault when re-implementing tolower() in C

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

The aim was to create a function that could convert all characters into lowercase to avoid caps sensitivity when asking a question, similar to that of `.lower()` in python. Currently the code below will come out with a "zsh: segmentation fault"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void lower(char *s[]){
    int length = sizeof(*s)/sizeof(*s[0]);
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (*s[i] >= 'A' && *s[i] <= 'Z'){
            s[i] += 32;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",*s);
}

int main(){
    char *variable[40];
    printf("what would you like to do: ");
    fgets(*variable, sizeof(*variable),stdin);
    lower(variable);
    printf("%s", *variable);
    return 0;

}
```

I have tried `int length = sizeof(*s)/sizeof(*s[0]);` and other methods of changing the length, including using a plain number, the same length assigned to the character length. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

P.S I don't want to use a pre-made function for this, as I want to better understand C and implement the function instead. Sorry for being difficult.

Comment: You really should be using `tolower()`...

Comment: What do you think `char *variable[40];` defines?

Comment: You have to get the length with `strlen` or pass it as a second argument to `lower`.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate because you have a lot of other issues, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues:

1. `char *variable[40];` - it is an array of 40 **pointers to `char`**. Those pointers are not initialized. When you dereference any of them, you invoke undefined behaviour.  You want an **array of `char`**
2. `int length = sizeof(*s)/sizeof(*s[0]);` it does not work in this scope. You will divide the size of pointer by size of pointer and you most likely will get 1. You want to use strlen. Also `s` needs to be **pointer to `char`**

```
void lower(char *s){
    size_t length = strlen(s);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'){
            s[i] += 'a' - 'A';
        }
    }
    printf("'%s'\n",s);
}

int main(){
    char variable[40];
    printf("what would you like to do: ");
    fgets(variable, sizeof(variable),stdin);
    lower(variable);
    printf("`%s`\n", variable);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4s4r7ffn1

But it is much better to use `tolower` function:

```
void lower(char *s){
    size_t length = strlen(s);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    printf("'%s'\n",s);
}
```

Comment: You do not need `strlen`. Delete it. Change `i< length` to `s[i]`

Comment: @EdHeal I am so impressed that you know how to iterate the C string without the use of `strlen`. But the answer is educational and I **show** how to get the size of the string **correctly** as OP does not understand it\

Comment: `tolower` is locale-aware, so it’s not even necessarily a better idea in practical applications – depends on the reason for lowercasing.

Comment: Thank you for the help. As you can probably tell I'm new to C programming, and to forums. The solution worked and I hope I can get my head around pointers better now. thanks for your time.